# Maximum principle for heat equation on infinite domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $u(x, t)$ be a solution of $u_t=u_{xx}$ in the domain $x>0, t>0$. We also have the initial condition $u(x,0)=g(x)$ and the boundary condition $u(0,t)=h(t)$. Do we have maximum principle in this case? Can we conclude that $u(x,t)$ is bounded if we assume both $g$ and $h$ are bounded? If not, what additional condition shall we impose? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need essentially the same condition as in the case of the domain $x\in\mathbb R$. That is, $$u(x,t)=o(e^{\epsilon|x|^2})$$
for every $\epsilon>0$.

**Edit**. Tikhonov provided an example of a non-trivial solution of the heat equation on the domain $\mathbb R$, with zero data. Take either its odd part, or the derivative of its even part with respect to $x$. It is a non-trivial solution of the heat equation in the domain $(0,+\infty)$ with zero Dirichlet boundary condition and zero initial data. If such a principle as the one considered by the MO author existed, this solution would be trivial.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to some good references about this topic? 

Comment: Is there a counter-example that the conclusion is not true if we don't assume this condition? Thanks!

Comment: @Chong. See my Edit.

Comment: It seems that this should be for some $\epsilon >0$, not every.